# Finding expected value: E(6^X)

Tags: probability

Let X∼Bin(10,0.2). Find E(6^X).

I know that E(X)=2, but I'm not sure how to find E(6^X).

Comment: Do you know about generating functions of discrete RVs?

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown not much about generating them...

Comment: Just to make sure this is not a notation thing, do you want to calculate $\mathbb{E}[6^X]$? or $\mathbb{E}[X^6]$?

Comment: @caverac E(6^X)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that in general if $X$ is a binomial random variable with $n$ trials each with probability of success $p$, then
$$
Et^X=\sum_{k\geq0}t^kP(X=k)=\sum_{k\geq0}\binom{n}{k}(tp)^k(1-p)^{n-k}=(tp+1-p)^n
$$
by the binomial theorem. Now put $t=6, p=0.2$ and $n=10$.

Answer (score 3):

Frequency distribution of the binomial: $p(n) = {10\choose n} 0.2^n 0.8^{10-n}$

And $E[6^n] = \sum_\limits{n=0}^{10} p(n) 6^n$

$\sum_\limits{n=0}^{10} ({10\choose n}0.2^n 0.8^{10-n})(6^n) = \sum_\limits{n=0}^{10} {10\choose n}(1.2)^n 0.8^{10-n}$

Now remember $(a+b)^{10} = \sum_\limits{n=0}^{10} {10\choose n}(a)^n b^{10-n}$

$E[6^n] = \sum_\limits{n=0}^{10} {10\choose n}(1.2)^n 0.8^{10-n} = (1.2+0.8)^{10} = 2^{10}$

Comment: +1 for avoiding shortcuts using probability generating functions or moment generating functions while staying brief